# Word that describes "allowing someone to identify with (it)"

Tags: single-word-requests

If I work on a strategy and want to highlight that the resulting process (sustainability management) needs to be designed such that it allows people to identify with it, what would be a single word describing this?

More specifically, it should be likely for a participant in the process to feel that the goals set forth in the process are their own goals.

Something in replacement of the single quotes in "The process needs to be 'identifiable with'"

The word occurs as a replacement of X in the sentence: "The process needs to be informed, adaptive, effective, X".

I haven't figured out a suitable thesaurus search that would get me close, and instead got stuck with irrelevant words such as "referable", "traceable".

Comment: *Inclusive*? Not a perfect fit, but in the right direction. Or if you can allow more than one word, "needs to be informed, adaptive, effective, and *inspire stakeholder buy-in*" (where you could replace "stakeholder" with a more specific word if applicable).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is **embraceable** too far from a clinical register, too cloying?

[YourDictionary](https://www.yourdictionary.com/embrace) refers one directly to the verb, which has a wealth of senses:

> **embrace** [transitive verb]
>
> 1. to clasp in the arms, usually as an expression of affection or
>      desire; hug
> 2. to accept readily; avail oneself of: *to embrace an opportunity* [/idea, strategy]
> 3. to take up or adopt, esp. eagerly or seriously: *to embrace a new*
>      *profession* [/plan, strategy]
> 4. to encircle; surround; enclose: *an isle embraced by the sea*
> 5. to include; contain: *biology embraces botany and zoology*
> 6. to take in mentally; perceive: *his glance embraced the scene*

Senses 2 and 3 license the metaphorical sense 'that may/will be readily/eagerly identified with', and the primary, literal, sense 1 has a warm connotation of user-friendliness.

..................

*Espouse* has sense (3) of 'embrace' above, but *espousable* is so rare as to sound distinctly odd.